# Certain fields in my List Views do not display even though they have data. Filter options do show the data options.

Tags: list-view

My Sharepoint list views are not displaying some data even though the data exists. I have full control and all permissions.

In the first image you can clearly see that nothing is displaying in the "Assigned To", "Created By" and "Modified By" columns. 
[image: Image 1]

However, if I view the filter, you can clearly see there are options:
[image: Image 2]

If I open one of these items, the data exists as well.

Any idea as to why these columns would not display values for items? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does your view have conditions?

Do you have any filtering baked into the view itself that may restrict the data from those columns being part of your result set?

Comment: I do have permissions filtering. But this is happening in ALL views and I have full access with no limit on my view.

Comment: This is happening on the two public views as well as my personal view. There are NO filters on the admin view. The list itself has permission limits to certain groups, but I am a part of all of those groups and I do have full permissions.